# New PC built won't start, keeps rebooting

Tags: cpu, reboot

I've just built a new PC and it was working fine for an hour or so. I was able to install Windows and there weren't any problems until I rebooted and now it won't start. The CPU fan tries to run but then the system keeps rebooting. I really don't know what's wrong!

I've made a video that describes my problem: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OyIPDifO-3c

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Please describe your problem in the question. Questions should be stand alone and not refer to external resources like videos (which may well be blocked for some readers).

Comment: I'm hearing a sound, which might be a beep. If so, check the manual of the mainboard, it will tell you what's not working.

Comment: Anyway, to have a shot at diagnosing the problem remotely we need to know what's showing up on the monitor, what changed since the PC was working, and what kinds of sounds the PC speakers make. If it's simply turning of, with nothing shown on the screen and no sound, it might be a problem with the PSU, or the load on the PSU.

Comment: Nothing shows up on the monitor. It doesn't get past the beep, trying to start, then it's rebooting. Those are all brand new components and they should be sufficient enough for what they're running. I'm running an i5, 650W Corsair PSU, ASUS Z97 motherboard, Corsair 16GB ram. Like I said, they're all brand new. Nothing else happens after the short beep (cannot find any beep codes for ASUS UEFI Bios).

Comment: Cleared / reset CMOS/BIOS? Start swaping (or just pulling unnecessary) parts & when it starts working again the last part is the bad one. Maybe start with a known good power supply, or check the voltages to make sure you won't be frying all the "good" parts with bad power

Answer (score 0):

It most probally a problem with the ram / the ram slot if it is beeping.
If you have any other ram lying around. try using that this is usually caused (if it is a ram problem) due to faulty ram(This might be your case as it is brand new) or due to voltage fluctuation. 
It can also be other reasons but usually beeping sound is manily related with ram